# Javascript inline function call from callback

Tags: javascript, for-loop, callback, inline

I have a function with a callback that checks whether or not a file exists on my server, with the result returned being either "true" or "false". My problem is that i am calling this "DoesFIleExist" function in a for-loop with the "id" calculated earlier in the function. The problem is that whenever one of the function calls is resolved and tries to call "AddResultToPage" it uses the id of the last for-loop iteration, when it should be using the id it was given when the function was called.

The "DoesFileExist" function takes a path and a callback as parameters.

Any help would be much appreciated, as i have looked online and on here but most of the answers i have found are relating to buttons and event listeners on the buttons.

```
DoesFileExist('/XML/'+id.trim()+'.xml',function(data) {
                        console.log(id.trim()+" "+data);
                        if (data == "true") {
                            (function () {
                                console.log("adding to page - "+id.trim());
                                AddResultToPage(id,false);
                            })();
                        }else{
                           console.log("the file does not exist");
                        }
```

Comment: You need a closure, look it up

Comment: You should take id out of the global space, and control it's scope with var and pass as parameter. Otherwise id can be anything. (someone else could change it to a number and break everything)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put it in a self invoking function:-

```
(function(id){
DoesFileExist('/XML/'+id.trim()+'.xml',function(data) {
                    console.log(id.trim()+" "+data);
                    if (data == "true") {
                        (function () {
                            console.log("adding to page - "+id.trim());
                            AddResultToPage(id,false);
                        })();
                    }else{
                       console.log("the file does not exist");
                    }
})}(id)) // now, your inner code has reference to correct id due to closure
```

What happens is, by the time your response from server is received, the for loop had been completed and id gets set to last value.

With closure, id will refer to the value passed in the function and not the one in loop

Comment: Thanks, this solved my problem. tyvm :)

Comment: welcome  .....:)

Answer (score -1):

You can use a specificId with let (that will stay in your scope, it is ES6). There is a related SO post about closures :
[How do JavaScript closures work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work?rq=1)

```
DoesFileExist('/XML/'+id.trim()+'.xml',function(data) {
                        let specificId = id;
                        console.log(id.trim()+" "+data);
                        if (data == "true") {
                            (function () {
                                console.log("adding to page - "+specificId.trim());
                                AddResultToPage(specificId,false);
                            })();
                        }else{
                           console.log("the file does not exist");
                        }
```